# Changing Colour of a Div with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So, I have a simple onclick function set up that is supposed to change the background of a div. Here is my JS code;

```
var colour = document.getElementById("backgroundColour");

function changeToColour1() {
    colour.style.backgroundColor = "#47535F";
}

function changeToColour2() {
    colour.style.backgroundColor = "#82A3B2";
}
```

Here is my HTML code;

```
<button id="colour1" class="colours" onclick="changeToColour1()"></button>

<button id="colour2" class="colours" onclick="changeToColour2()"></button>

<div id="backgroundColour"></div>
```

How would I get the div to change its colour when the button is clicked?

Comment: Looks like the color is not being reflected since there is no content inside the div. Give it a fixed width and height or some content to see the change. There is nothing wrong with your code. Also try to avoid using inline event handlers.

Comment: I agree with Sushanth's answer. However, apart from that, I saw that without changing much of your code, if you just assign the functions to 'window' object, it works. e.g. window.changeToColour1. Not exactly sure why it's happening, but probably it's because onclick event handler is looking within window's scope. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

a much cleaner way of doing this would be to just use javascript to add classes to your elements, and let CSS control the colors.

```
$('#colour1').on('click',function(){
  $('#backgroundColour').removeClass('colour1 colour2').addClass('colour1');
});

$('#colour2').on('click',function(){
  $('#backgroundColour').removeClass('colour1 colour2').addClass('colour2');
});
```

and in your CSS put

```
#backgroundColour.colour1 {
  background-color: #47535F;
}

#backgroundColour.colour2 {
  background-color: #82A3B2;
}
```

Comment: what if he doesn't want to use jquery?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using vanilla javascript, but jQuery is very useful for those who aren't great at javascript. Handling cross-browser issues in plain js is an artform that takes time. It doesn't appear to me that he is to that point yet.

Comment: Makes sense. Just that I prefer to try to give pure JS answer if questions uses one. Btw, do you have any idea about the issue mentioned in my comment to question?

Answer (score 1):

- Give the Div a proper width and height or some content, otherwise the
  div cannot be seen.
- Avoid inline event handlers and use DOM3 event handlers.
- You can also use **data-*** attributes to store the colors instead of
  having a seperate function for each button.

**HTML**

```
<button id="colour1" class="colours" data-color="#47535F" >Click me</button>

<button id="colour2" class="colours" data-color="#82A3B2">Click me</button>

<div id="backgroundColour">fff</div>
```

**JS**

```
var colourDiv = document.getElementById("backgroundColour");

var colours = document.getElementsByClassName('colours');

for(var i=0; i< colours.length; i++) {
    colours[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
         var color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
         colourDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm7Rw/)**

Comment: Instead of hardcoding color in data attributes, I would define classes for those colors & will add them using javascript whenever needed.

Comment: That should be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost i recommend you to use JQuery for the task you are trying to accomplish, im recommending you do for the simple fact JQuery is a simple straight forward library for javascript that makes our lives as coders a lot more simple, now that im done saying that here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
        }
        #changing{ /*this is the css for our javascript*/
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            right:0px;
            bottom:0px;
        }
        #wrap{ /*this is to keep the browse menu that has your buttons from disappearing below the changing div*/
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:40px;;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-bottom:5px solid #D8D8D8;
            border-radius:0px;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index:10;
        }
        #button1, #button2{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            position:fixed;
        }
        #button1{
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
        #button2{
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
        }
    </style>

    <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="wrap">
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="click me" />
            <input type="button" id="button2" value="click me 2" />
        </div>
        <div id="changing">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#changing").css("background-color", "#47535F");//changes the color of the background to #47535F
        })
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#changing").css("background-color", "#82A3B2");//changes the color of the background to #82A3B2
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in this code we use inline css and javascript with the JQuery library, we first start the document how we should always start a html document by adding the DOCTYPE and our meta tags with the attributes content-type and content-language we also add a title.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

next we add our our script to import the JQuery library, i usually go with the google hosted version because its usually up and running and i dont have to constantly update it , google does that for you, the only thing you need to do is add the new url in the src to replace the old version of JQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>

    <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

next we add our html, in our html we added two buttons and placed them in a div called wrap and added our changing div and placed both the changing div and the wrap div into a div called body-container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>

    <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="wrap">
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="click me" />
            <input type="button" id="button2" value="click me 2" />
        </div>
        <div id="changing">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now time to add the icing to the cake with our script and css, here we added our css to determine the style of our page we made ours so that the browse menu were are buttons are located scroll with the page and are always onto, now onto the script, we made our script so that if the button is pressed it will change the background of the div body-container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
        }
        #changing{ /*this is the css for our javascript*/
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            right:0px;
            bottom:0px;
        }
        #wrap{ /*this is to keep the browse menu that has your buttons from disappearing below the changing div*/
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:40px;;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-bottom:5px solid #D8D8D8;
            border-radius:0px;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index:10;
        }
        #button1, #button2{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            position:fixed;
        }
        #button1{
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
        #button2{
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
        }
    </style>

    <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="wrap">
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="click me" />
            <input type="button" id="button2" value="click me 2" />
        </div>
        <div id="changing">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#changing").css("background-color", "#47535F");//changes the color of the background to #47535F
        })
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#changing").css("background-color", "#82A3B2");//changes the color of the background to #82A3B2
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i hoped this helped, for any information on JQuery i recommend you go visit their online documents, they have a lot of useful info there, here is the link

http://api.jquery.com/

you can also check out w3chools they have a lot of good stuff on JQuery as well as many other programming languages, here is the link

http://www.w3schools.com/

best of luck with your project or learning the javascript language (=

Comment: This is just my 0.02 - jQuery is great, and it really does simplify our lives...BUT would you really suggest loading an 80KB (30 gzipped) just to change the color of an element (or, even look into addressing this via CSS...), when a few lines of JS will do the job? Personally, I think it's great that people would want to learn JS first... At least then they'll understand how jQuery works behind the scene. Again, just my 0.02 :)

Comment: i totally agree that javascript is a awesome scripting language to know, i just think JQuery fits the bill here, plus JQuery is javascript its a library made in javascript to help you write shorter faster and more dynamically powerful apps in the javascript langauge.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I love jQuery and it does do a lot of things right. Again, I'm just questioning the use of a full fledge library when a few lines of code will do the same thing. Consider users on a slower connection (landline, mobile) or a lower end device (older tablets, older smartphones) and they'll appreciate the consideration of doing things with plain vanilla JS vs a library :)